# How to echo an PHP tag?

Tags: php, printing, tags, echo

I'm trying to echo a PHP tag by doing this:

```
echo "<?php echo \"test\"; ?>";
```

The result should be just "test" without quotes, but my code isn't working. What is happening is that nothing is shown on the page, but the source code is `"<?php echo "teste"; ?>"`

Most of you will want to know why I want to do this. I'm trying to make my own template system; the simplest way is just using `file_get_contents` and replacing what I want with `str_replace` and then using `echo`.

The problem is, that in the template file, I have to have some PHP functions that doesn't work when I echo the page, is there another simple way to do this? Or if you just answer my question will help a lot!

Here is an example of what I am trying to accomplish:

template.tpl:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>[__TITULO__]</title>
</head>
<body >
<p>Nome: [__NOME__] <br />
Email: <a href="mailto:[__EMAIL__]">[__EMAIL__]</a><br />

<?php
if ($cidade != "") {?>
    Cidade: [__CIDADE__]<br />
    <?php
}
?>

Telefone: ([__DDD__])&nbsp;&nbsp;[__TELEFONE__] <br />
Fax:
([__DDDFAX__])&nbsp;&nbsp;[__FAX__] <br />
Interesse: [__INTERESSE__]<br />
Mensagem: 
[__MENSAGEM__] </p>
</body>
</html>
```

index.php

```
<?php
$cidade = "Teste";
$file = file_get_contents('template.php');

$file = str_replace("[__TITULO__]","Esse Título é téste!", $file);
$file = str_replace("[__NOME__]","Cárlos", $file);
$file = str_replace("[__EMAIL__]","moura.kadu@gmail.com", $file); 

if ($cidade != "") {
    $file = str_replace("[__CIDADE__]",$cidade, $file); 
}

echo $file;

?>
```

I can solve all this just not showing the div that has no content. like if i have a template, and in it i have 2 divs:

```
<div id="content1">[__content1__]</div>
<div id="content2">[__content2__]</div>
```

if the time that i set the content to replace the template I set the content1 and not set content 2 the div content2 will not show...

Comment: Look up "escaping" in the PHP manual.

Comment: `<?php echo "teste"; ?>` is malformed HTML, that's why it doesn't appear in the rendered output (it should be in the source though). Are you looking for a template solution?: [Twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/), [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/), [Dwoo](http://dwoo.org/), [More...](https://www.google.com/search?q=php+template+engine). Trust me - your current idea is bad. OR --- Are you trying to output visible PHP code snippets to the browser?

Comment: its not it, i want the code in echo render as php code as if it was in the source page.

Comment: the result should NOT be just "test" without quotes

Answer (score 3):

Use `htmlspecialchars`

That will convert the < > to `&lt;` and `&gt;`

Answer (score 0):

You are dealing with two sets of source code here that should never be confused - the server code (PHP, which is whatever is in the `<?php ?>` tags) and the client (or browser) code which includes all HTML tags. The output of the server code is *itself* code that gets sent to the browser. Here you *are* in fact successfully echoing a PHP tag, but it is meaningless to the browser, which is why the browser ignores it and doesn't show anything unless you look at the client code that got sent to it.

To implement templates in this style, either they should not have any PHP code, or the resulting string (which you have stored in `$file`) should itself be executed  as though it were PHP, rather than echoing it straight to the client. There are various ways to do this. One is to parse out the PHP tags in the string, echo everything that is not within the PHP tags and run `eval()` on everything that is.